# Present long link list in a readable way HTML

Tags: css, html

I have 25 links in one page. I present them in two rows.
I present them like this:

```
link1 - link2  - link3 - ...
link12 - .... link25
```

If they have priorities between each other I would present them in a tag cloud. But nearly all of the links have same priority.

What would be the better ways to present links in more human readable format?
I tried this:
`<span>link1<span> <code>link2</code>  <span>link3<span> <code>link4</code>` etc..

**Edit**: They can't be more subgrouped. This is minimized version.
Links expresses country names, person names, book titles etc.
I don't plan to subgroup them.
For example:
"Australia" "Der Kampf" "Michael Jackson" "Grapes of Wrath Madonna"

Design is to user select a title with selective perception. So to trigger user's perception I plan to put them in one paragraph.

Comment: Do they have any classifications? Can they be grouped? Does an alphabetical order make sense? Do all of them need to be displayed at the same time or can you rotate a link viewer? Would it make sense to use images as icons for the different links creating a 5x5 matrix?

Comment: I'd personally start by questioning if there is a better way of dealing with it than having 25 links all together. Can they be subdivided into groups? Can you have just one link instead leading to an index page which then allows you to have all the 25 links on a page where you could do something a bit nicer with them? Sadly this question is not really answerable without knowing what the rest of your page looks like. There is no one good answer that fits all situations. I'd say the best way to do 25 links is on 25 lines but this might not fit with what you want...

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. You want a design suggestion but on the other hand you say that you want them to be equally emphasized. What's wrong with just listing them on one line (or be it a few lines)?

Comment: This is a design question, not programming even in a broad sense of the word, and the question is far too vaguely formulated, without any illustrative example. The coding part of the job is probably rather trivial, once one has decided the goal (the desired rendering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tryouts I have found out that best approach is using button links.
Anchor texts became button titles and buttons link to the URLs.
Main advantage is easily changing button colors (twitter bootstrap) and I don't need to be curious about the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Used to `white-space` properties as like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a>
<a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a>
<a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a><a href="#">Link text</a>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.parent {
white-space:nowrap;
}

    .parent a{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space:normal;
    }
```

[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/3Le0lUPE)

Answer (score 1):

Rohit was on the right track, but I feel that this might be a bit easier to read if you still want them on two lines:

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Link1</a>, <a href="#">Link2</a>, <a href="#">Link3</a>, <a href="#">Link4</a>, 
        <a href="#">Link5</a>, <a href="#">Link6</a>, <a href="#">Link7</a>, <a href="#">Link8</a>, 
        <a href="#">Link9</a>, <a href="#">Link10</a>, <a href="#">Link11</a>, <a href="#">Link12</a>, 
        <a href="#">Link13</a>, <br><a href="#">Link14</a>, <a href="#">Link15</a>, <a href="#">Link16</a>, 
        <a href="#">Link17</a>, <a href="#">Link18</a>, <a href="#">Link19</a>, <a href="#">Link20</a>, 
        <a href="#">Link21</a>, <a href="#">Link22</a>, <a href="#">Link23</a>, <a href="#">Link24</a>, 
        <a href="#">Link25</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.parent a{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/SA5tC7pS)